# How to set background color to UILabel text only

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uilabel

I'm working the App where i need to set the label like attached image. Please let me know if anyone have any idea?

[image: Image Demo]

Comment: Maybe with `NSAttributedString` and `NSBackgroundAttributeName`?

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this

```
NSString *yourString1=@"What Does your friends really";
NSString *yourString2=@"Think of your spouce?";

NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@..\n",yourString1];
NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@,,",yourString2];
NSString *str3=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",str1,str2];    

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[str1 stringByAppendingString:str2]];
NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@".."];
NSRange range1 = [str3 rangeOfString:@",,"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:range];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:range1];    
[attributedString addAttribute: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor orangeColor] range: NSMakeRange(0, str1.length)];
[attributedString addAttribute: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor redColor] range: NSMakeRange(str1.length, str2.length)];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:5];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [str2 length])];

lblTest.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Output of this Code:

[image]

Comment: What is your output for NSString *str1=@"What Does your friends really           "; // some space in the end ? End Space background colour must be covered. But your solution does not.

Comment: Now this could be the solution. Thanks for helping other :)

Answer (score 3):

If using an attributed string with a background color on the string doesn't work then you might need to create 2 separate labels with space between them and set the background color on each.

Answer (score 3):

May be you need some space with that background color where text has ended. I have solved this problem in my own tricks. Add some comma or point to separate the string. Then apply this to the string. No extra label need to create.

```
  NSArray *aArray = [@" Font Size  .k" componentsSeparatedByString:@".k"];

NSMutableAttributedString *fulltext=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];

NSMutableAttributedString *title1=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[aArray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSMutableAttributedString *title2=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[aArray objectAtIndex:1]];

//[title1 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:84.0/255.0 blue:49.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(0,title1.length)];
[title1 addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
               value:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:84.0/255.0 blue:49.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
               range:NSMakeRange(0, title1.length)];
[title1 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
               value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:(isIpad||isIPadPro)?19.0f:16.0f]
               range:NSMakeRange(0,title1.length)];

[title2 addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,title2.length)];
[title2 addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
               value:[UIColor clearColor]
               range:NSMakeRange(0, title2.length)];
[title2 addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
               value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:(isIpad||isIPadPro)?19.0f:16.0f]
               range:NSMakeRange(0,title2.length)];

[fulltext appendAttributedString:title1];
[fulltext appendAttributedString:title2];

self.textLabel.attributedText = fulltext;
```

My output is like:

[image]

Now make the K's background (title2) clear, so you can get the spaces after text end with your space!

Answer (score 2):

```
//setting dummy text to label
self.lbLog.text=@"This is Simple Text With Red background Color";

//creating attributed string 
NSMutableAttributedString *attribString =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.lbLog.text];

//setting background color to attributed text
[attribString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
          value:[UIColor redColor]
          range:NSMakeRange(0, attribString.length)];

//setting attributed text to label
self.lbLog.attributedText = attribString;
```

Comment: @ Mahesh   Thanks for your reply but it's only changing background color. actualy i want to set the color to every line of single label with gap transperent

Comment: @user3306145 Then you need to use `NSParagraphAttributeName` and `NS(Mutable)ParagraphStyle` where you can set line height if needed.

Comment: Ok, but  i need just like two label with diffrent frame. if i impleted as per ur suggestion now it having the space betwwen lines but  i want space with clear color.

Answer (score 1):

```
lblText.backgroundColor=UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use separate label where you set background colour of the label if background colour of all label text is same for all text in label otherwise **for different background colour** for some of the text you need to use **NSMutableAttributedString**.

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:29.0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:145.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: It will change background color. We need to change the only textcolor.

Comment: label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:29.0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:145.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 0):

Use two custom Label (or instead label use uiview as your background), One is for your background,set backgroundcolor as clear color and another label is for ur text set backgroundcolor as your desire color.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with the help of UItextview. I did that, I will post the code very soon.